# Get animation steps in svg.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, svg.js

The [`svg.js`](http://svgjs.com/) library [allows us to animate the elements](http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#animating-elements):

```
rect.animate().move(150, 150)
```

Is it possible to call a function at very change (step), like [we do in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) using the `step` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`during`](https://github.com/wout/svg.js#during) function is the answer:

```
var draw = SVG('drawing').size(300, 300)
var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' })
rect.animate().move(200, 0).during(function(pos) {
    console.log(pos); // a value between 0 and 1
});
```

> #### during()
>
> If you want to perform your own actions during the animations you can use the `during()` method:
>
> ```
> var position
>     , from = 100
>     , to   = 300
>
> rect.animate(3000).move(100, 100).during(function(pos) {
>   position = from + (to - from) * pos 
> })
> ```
>
> Note that `pos` is `0` in the beginning of the animation and `1` at the end of the animation.
>
> To make things easier a morphing function is passed as the second argument. This function accepts a from and to value as the first and second argument and they can be a number, unit or hex color:
>
> ```
> var ellipse = draw.ellipse(100, 100).attr('cx', '20%').fill('#333')
>
> rect.animate(3000).move(100, 100).during(function(pos, morph) {
>
> // numeric values
>   ellipse.size(morph(100, 200), morph(100, 50))
>
>  // unit strings
>   ellipse.attr('cx', morph('20%', '80%'))
>
>  // hex color strings
>   ellipse.fill(morph('#333', '#ff0066'))
> })
> ```
>
> returns: **`SVG.FX`**

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c8qbjbb4/)